# Java/Hibernate Jackson does relationship serialisation only for first object

Tags: java, hibernate, jackson, playframework-2.0

My Jackson Serialisation does only sometimes serialize my relationships.

Relationship User -> Company (n:1)

```
User { 
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = models.Company.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
    @JoinColumn(name = "usr_company", nullable = true)
    @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId=false)
    private Company company;
}
```

For serialization I use

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();    
mapper.disable(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION);
mapper.writerWithView(viewClass).writeValueAsString(Object);
```

Assuming I have User 1+2+3 in Company A and User 3+4 in Company B then the JSON **Output of Jackson** is as following (mixes up IDs and Entities):

```
{ name:'User 1', Company: {name:'test',...}},  
{ name:'User 2', Company: 'ID1'},  
{ name:'User 3', Company: 'ID2'},  
{ name:'User 4', Company: {name:'test',...}},
```

So on the first time the company appears, it gets serialized, on the second time it does not.

And I have really now idea why :(

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your json format is not correct here:

```
{ name:'User 2', Company: 'ID'},
```

Company is an entity, not a string literal, when you create the json you must do it like:

```
{ name:'User 1', Company: {name:'test',...}},  
{ name:'User 2', Company: {id:'ID'}},  
{ name:'User 3', Company: {id:'ID'}},  
{ name:'User 4', Company: {name:'test',...}},
```

in order jackson recognizes it with your mapping

Comment: Thank you for your comment, so I think I did not explain it well. Jackson serializes it the first time as entity but the second time it just shows a String. I have no idea why :/